# Curl not working on mac?

Tags: macos, shell, curl

I am trying to install a file using curl on my mac through a shell script. I am running 10.8. here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
curl -s https://website.com -o /usr/local/bin/folder
echo "success"
```

There are no errors but it doesn't download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the directory (/usr/local/bin/folder) exists and it is writable.

The -s option for curl means that it won't output any information or errors, so try without it.

Answer (score 3):

`-s` suppresses output, including errors. Change that to `-sS` to print an error if it fails, and you'll see that the problem is:

```
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 220)
```

220 is the error EBADF, meaning (in this case) it can't write to the output file.
Evidently you have to specify the *file* name, not a folder in which to put the file. Use

```
curl -sS https://website.com -o /usr/local/bin/folder/page.html
```

You'll also need to make sure you can create files in that folder.

Comment: I tried the -sS thing, still no errors and nothing is installing. I think the problem is that I can't download files into that folder. Is there a way I can get around that?